# AlchemyAPI C will not compile on Ubuntu - keywordspp specifically

Tags: c, ubuntu, bitnami, alchemyapi

I really like playing with the Alchemy API REST api and have tried the php sdk but am trying to compile the API and keep getting a very bizarre issue when I try to do a make.

This is when trying to compile on an Ubuntu instance on AWS EC2 using the Bitnami AMI.

Here's the output:

```
libtool: link: g++ -g -O2 -o .libs/keywordspp keywordspp.o  ../src/.libs/libalchemyapi.so -L/opt/bitnami/common/lib /opt/bitnami/common/lib/libxml2.so -lz /opt/bitnami/common/lib/libiconv.so -lm /opt/bitnami/common/lib/libcurl.so -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/opt/bitnami/common/lib
keywordspp.o: In function `operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >':
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/basic_string.h:2506: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'
keywordspp.o: In function `operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >':
/usr/include/c++/4.4/ostream:510: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'
keywordspp.o: In function `operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >':
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/basic_string.h:2506: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [keywordspp] Error 1
```

Comment: I should add the compiler is gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1)

Answer (score 0):

Setting LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4 before running configure should make it works.

```
$ ./autobuild.sh
$ export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4
$ ./configure
$ make
```